Stalk of coherent sheaves and pushforward/pullback
Let $X$ be a Noetherian scheme.  Let $\mathcal F$ be a  coherent  $\mathcal O_X$-module. Let $x\in X$. There is a natural morphism Spec $\mathcal O_{X, x}\xrightarrow{j} X$. Define $\mathcal F(x):=j_*(\widetilde {\mathcal F_x})$.
Is it true that $j^* \mathcal F\cong \widetilde {\mathcal F_x} $ and $\mathcal F(x)$ a coherent $\mathcal O_X$-module?
